# Can't copy files to Windows disk

Tags: windows

I can't copy files to the volume where i've installed Windows (to C:\ local disk). I could copy to that disk before, but after reinstalled my windows i can't copy there anything!

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu thinks that you've probably got a dirty filesystem in Windows. To fix this:

## in Windows:

- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- disable hibernation, type `powercfg /h off`
- check your file system, type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve running `chkdsk` at next reboot
- reboot into Windows
- reboot into Ubuntu, and your disk should be fine now